# Spring security causing AngularJS to send GET requests instead of POST requests

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, rest, spring-security

I have a login form which is handled by an AngularJS login controller. I also have a corresponding Spring controller which receives the login credentials from this form. This form works when I have Spring security disabled. I'm able to send credentials, check it against the database, and receive the user object in the front end. HOWEVER, when I have Spring security enabled with a `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`, it causes this error message:

```
o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : Request method 'GET' not supported
```

In the Chrome developer console, it's saying "405 GET not supported".

Here's the AngularJS controller:

```
<div id="home" class="border-shadow" ng-app="landing">
    <div class="col-lg-5" ng-controller="authentication">
                        <form role="form">              
                            <div class="form-group row row-margin">
                                <div class="col-lg-5">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="credentials.username" placeholder="Username" required>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-5">       
                                    <input type="password" class="form-control" ng-model="credentials.password" placeholder="Password" required>
                                    <a href="#" class="forget"> Forgot Your Password</a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-2">
                                    <button ng-click="login()" class="btn btn-success">Log in</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <p>{{error}}</p>
                            <p>{{user.username}}</p>
                            <p>{{user.email}}</p>
                            <p>{{user.phoneNumber}}</p>
                        </form>  
      </div>
</div>
```

Here's the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` (Having this class causes the POST request from the AngularJS controller to create the "405 GET not supported" error:

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
@Order(-20)
public class CustomWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    public CustomWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.parentAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
      http
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/css/**", "/js/**", "/images/**", "/fonts/**", "/videos/**")
        .permitAll()
        .and()
          .formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()
        .and()
          .authorizeRequests()                      
          .antMatchers("/", "/join", "/login", "/about", "/contact", "/index.html")
          .permitAll()
        .and().authorizeRequests()
          .anyRequest().authenticated()                            
        .and().exceptionHandling()
          .authenticationEntryPoint(new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/"))
        .and()
          .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/index.html").permitAll()
        .and()
          .csrf().disable();
    }

}
```

And here is the Spring controller:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<BusinessUser> login(@RequestBody BusinessUser inputUser) {
        BusinessUser requestedUser = businessUserService.findByUsername(inputUser.getUsername());
        if(requestedUser != null)
            if(BCrypt.checkpw(inputUser.getPassword(), requestedUser.getPassword()))
                return new ResponseEntity<>(requestedUser, HttpStatus.OK);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
```

And just to add more information, here's the main:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories  ("com.test.app.repositories")
@EntityScan             ("com.test.app.model")
@ComponentScan          (basePackages={"com.test.app"})
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class App {

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }

}
```

Again, just to clarify, the login system works perfectly fine when I do NOT have the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` class. Whenever I add this class, it causes a "405 GET not supported" error which doesn't make any sense to me as I'm sending POST with the Angular controller.

**EDIT** My AngularJS controller. (Sorry, forgot it):

```
<script>
    angular.module('landing', [])
    .controller('authentication',
      function($rootScope, $scope, $http, $location) {
      $scope.credentials = {};
      $scope.login = function() {
        $http.post('http://localhost:8090/login', $scope.credentials, {
          headers : {
            "content-type" : "application/json"
          }
        }).success(function(data, status) {
            $scope.user = data;
        }).error(function(data, status) {
            $scope.error = "Invalid username or password";
        })
      };
    });
</script>
```

Comment: try by providing method="post" in form

Comment: @BhaumikThakkar I tried that already. `formmethod=post`. It doesn't change anything unfortunately. Whenever I allow the back end controller to accept GET requests, I get a 400 error instead. Says `http://localhost:8090/login?error 400 malformed request`.

Comment: please show me your controller .js file

Comment: @BhaumikThakkar Didn't even realize I forgot to post that. I posted it now.

Comment: where you are passing your data to back end in your angular's function?

Comment: @BhaumikThakkar $scope.credentials. In the form, there's credentials.username and credentials.password. Sending the data this way works whenever I do NOT have the `@EnableWebSecurity` and when I get rid of the class that extends `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`. It's whenever I enable Spring security (OAuth 2.0) that it causes an error. As you can see, I'm sending a `$http.post` request but for some reason it says "405 GET not allowed"